# docker network port binding

Tags: docker, containers

I was playing around with docker and containers. 
I have the docker engine setup on a Ubuntu box(running in VMware player) and am trying to bind the daemon to the network port with the following command:

```
root@ubuntu:~# docker -H 10.0.0.7:2375 -d &
[1] 10046
root@ubuntu:~# flag provided but not defined: -d
See 'docker --help'.
```

Why is it that the -d parameter throwing it off. I am very new to Linux so any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `docker daemon`, not `docker -d`. This has been moved to `dockerd` in 1.12 but calling `docker daemon` still works there (it's just a pass through to the new command).

Comment: Yes, just realized that as I was going through the docs. Thanks though @BMitch